# Flutter: How to maintain a unique URL for each page in the application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an e-commerce application (similar to Amazon) using Flutter and need help with the following query:

The application displays hundreds of items in a category, when a user clicks on an item they're redirected to a page containing item info. How do I maintain a unique URL for each and every item listed on my application? (Please view the screenshot attached for more clarity)

[Catalog Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVy9r.jpg) ->
[Item Description Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lBv2.png)

I tried the following, it works but I don't think this is the right approach:

```
MaterialApp(
    routes: {
        '/itemOne': (context) => <ItemOneWidget>,
        '/itemTwo': (context) => <ItemTwoWidget>
    },
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use parametrised routes, meaning that you provide an extra argument when opening a new page. In your example: You have a generic product page and provide the product ID as an extra argument to customise the page.

The thing is, routing in flutter apps can be achieved in many different ways. I will provide a solution for native flutter without any further dependencies. But if you would like to go with a navigation framework such as the widely popular `go_router`, the syntax will look different.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    if (settings.name == "productScreen") {
      final productID = settings.arguments as int;

      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return ProductScreen(
            title: "Item number {productID}",
          );
        },
      );
    }
);
```

You can then navigate to the page via

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  "productScreen",
  arguments: 42
);
```

Read more about this approach in the flutter [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).